# I get this error : java.lang.NullPointerException:lock ==null

Tags: android, asp.net, json, web-services, android-asynctask

I am trying to get json from localhost in Android. But I have some problem to get Json .
   I am  getting this error : java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null.
 Please help me how can I solve this problem. My code  is here :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment   {

    View v;
    JSONArray android=null;
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    TextView id;
    TextView name;
    TextView price;
    ConnectionTask mConTask = null;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    JsonCreator jsonCreator = new JsonCreator();
    private static  String url="http://localhost:59124/Products.aspx";
    private static final String TAG_OS = "android";
      private static final String TAG_ID = "ProductID";
      private static final String TAG_PRODUCTNAME = "ProductName";
      private static final String TAG_PRICE = "UnitPrice";

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         new ConnectionTask().execute();
    }

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            return v;
    }

    public class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
             id = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.id);
             name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
             price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.price);
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Yükleniyor... ",true ,true);

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( JSONObject json) {

            if(json == null){

                //İnternet kontrolü
                if(!Constants.isInternetAvailable(getActivity())){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Lütfen internet bağlantınızı kontrol ediniz.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
                //İnternet var ise veri boş
                else{
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hiçbir veri bulunmamaktadır.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                } 
            }
            else{
                    try {
                    // Getting JSON Array from URL
                    android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCTNAME);
                    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_PRODUCTNAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                    oslist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                            R.layout.list_v,
                            new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_PRODUCTNAME, TAG_PRICE }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.id,R.id.name, R.id.price});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);   
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mConTask = null;
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

.NET code is here :

```
 string stroutput = "";

                   try
            {
                string conStr = @"data source=.;database=Kelepir;Integrated Security=True;";
                //string conStr = "data source=.;database=Northwind;user=Android;password=123456;Integrated Security=True;";
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
                connection.Open();
                string myquery = "select ProductID,ProductName,CategoryName,UnitPrice from Products";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myquery, connection);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                var rowList = new List<object>();       
                while (reader.Read())
               {
                var nes = new
               { 

                ProductID = reader["ProductID"].ToString(),
                ProductName = reader["ProductName"].ToString(),
                CategoryName = reader["CategoryName"].ToString(),
                UnitPrice = reader["UnitPrice"].ToString()
             };
             rowList.Add(nes);

        }
                var serializeMe = new { android = rowList };
             stroutput = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(serializeMe );
             Response.Write(stroutput);

            }
                  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                stroutput = "ERROR : " + ex.Message;
            }
```

and LogChat :

```
04-20 21:00:40.312: E/Buffer Error(4742): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
    04-20 21:00:40.312: E/JSON Parser(4742): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 4742
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10055 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:813)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:563)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.jsonlib.Constants.isInternetAvailable(Constants.java:12)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment$ConnectionTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:91)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment$ConnectionTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:1)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    04-20 21:00:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

localhost output is here :

```
{"android":[{"ProductID":"1","ProductName":"Şeker","CategoryName":"Tatlı","UnitPrice":"20"},{"ProductID":"2","ProductName":"Kuruyemiş","CategoryName":"Tuzl","UnitPrice":"200"},{"ProductID":"3","ProductName":"Baklagil","CategoryName":"Sebze","UnitPrice":"100"},{"ProductID":"4","ProductName":"Bulgur","CategoryName":"Sebze","UnitPrice":"10"}]}
```

Thanks ..

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't debug your program?

Comment: app has stoped when I debugging program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`

mostly occurs when there is an error in your server code, and its not returning a valid JSON.

Comment: So how to fix problem  ?

Comment: In your JSON Parser, use `Log.i` to print your received json string and let me know with results. And have you tested your .NET code that a json string is returned for both success and failure scenarios ?

Comment: Thanks I will use Log and I will return to you )

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Genymotion or some other emulator you must use `http://10.0.3.2/` instead of `http://localhost/`  ... You can try from explorer on your emulator, if you can't connect to `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` then try `http://10.0.2.2` for standard emulator or `http://10.0.3.2` for Genymotion.